# NodeJS server: How to preserved int tuple data inside JSON POST without the int being converted into scientific notations?

Tags: node.js

I was running this `server.js` code that will received JSON data from the URL with request of `/temperature_humidity`

```
var express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
var port = 3340;
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cors = require('cors');
var dateToday = new Date();
var yearToday = dateToday.getFullYear();
var sec_between_log_entries      = 60;
var latest_temperature           = 0.0;
var latest_humidity              = 0.0;
var latest_value_datetime;
var temp_hum_json_enc = null;
var temp_hum_json = null;
var dateTime = new Date().toISOString().replace('T', ' ').substr(0, 19);
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const {spawn} = require('child_process');


app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
//app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 3340));

console.log(dateTime);

app.post('/temperature_humidity', function(req, res) {
    temp_hum_json_enc = req.body;
    console.log(temp_hum_json_enc);
    temp_hum_json_enc.ecc = Number(temp_hum_json_enc.ecc);
    echo(temp_hum_json_enc.ecc);
    const data_enc = JSON.stringify(temp_hum_json_enc);
    //res.send(temp_hum_json);
    fs.writeFile('dataenc.json', data_enc, function (err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('Saved!');
    });
});



app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
  console.log('run at port', app.get('port'));
})
```

The JSON data that got post looks like this before.

```
{
    "ecc": [
        37145707901129672682416989774084502293221716458590628654421340970276245677527, 
        33014636812082400626637661417910979580845984854782604607505156355753282784758
    ],
....
}
```

But when the JSON data got received on the server it becomes like this (the number inside tuple is different this time, but it's similar case), it got converted into scientific notations.

```
{
    "ecc":[4.2936222087170214e+76,2.7590627063101124e+76],
    ...

}
```

How can I preserved the whole number inside this tuple without it being converted into scientific notations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON only supports [double-precision floating-point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) numbers, which only allow storing exact integers in the range [-(2**53)+1, (2**53)-1].
Any number out of that range has to be somehow stored as its closest floating-point approximation.

The numbers you sent from the server are much larger than (2**53)-1. Therefore, they cannot be stored in their exact integer value.

What you can do is to store those number as Strings, such as '1234567890', or use some other data format instead of JSON.

Source: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-6

> . Note that when such software is used, numbers that are integers and
> are in the range [-(2**53)+1, (2**53)-1] are interoperable in the
> sense that implementations will agree exactly on their numeric
> values.

Comment: Thank you! Now I'm going to change the way of data format inside this JSON to send the string of it instead. Another thing, how can I convert this String inside this tuple/list inside the received JSON back to numbers and apply the converted data back to the same JSON in NodeJS?

Comment: you can use `BigInt('12345')` to convert the string back to a large integer. JavaScript has [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) to store exact integer value larger than 2**53-1.